# how to handle overflow of a div so that it scrolls

Tags: css, flexbox

I have have this following snippet and was wondering if anyone can help get the overflow corrected so the element with id "list" can be scrolled vertically while sized to the same height as the first two divs. Thank you!

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#first, #second {
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  border: solid;
}
#list {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.item {
  border: solid;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<div id="first">
</div>
<div id="second">
</div>
<div id="list">
<div class="item">
item 1
</div>
<div class="item">
item 2
</div>
<div class="item">
item 3
</div>
<div class="item">
item 4
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to restrict the `height` of `#list` and use `overflow-x: hidden;` on it. Then it will scroll. Note the `width: 165px` setting for `#list` to allow the border to be not covered by the scrollbar.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#parent {
  display: flex;
}

#first,
#second {
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  border: solid;
}

#list {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 165px;
}

.item {
  border: solid;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="first">
  </div>
  <div id="second">
  </div>
  <div id="list">
    <div class="item">
      item 1
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item 2
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item 3
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I should have clarified that I'd like to have the same effect by setting the max height on the parent instead of on div#list. Is this possible?